# Checking the logic: Number of words of each length

Tags: c, string, algorithm, logic

I am trying to write a program in C to find the number of words of each length in the input. I am aware this question has been asked before but it is **not a duplicate** as I want to find the error in my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c,i,len,nw,state,tally[100];
    nw=len=state=0;

    for(i=0;i<100;++i)
        tally[i]=0;
    
    while(c=getchar()!=EOF)
    {
        state=0;
        if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')
        {
            state=0;
            printf("Hey");
            if(nw==1)
            {
                ++tally[len];
                nw=0;
                len=0;
            }
        }
        else if(nw==0)
        {
            state=1;
            nw=1;
            len++;
        }
        else if(state==1)
            len++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<100;++i)
        printf("%d", tally[i]);
}
```

Suppose my input is "ab cd". Then the output is just 00000.... The program never prints a "hey" which it should do once. I don't see what is the mistake which prevents the program to execute the code inside the first "if"-condition.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `c=getchar()!=EOF` --> `(c = getchar()) != EOF` And yes, this is an exact duplicate. I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: @user3386109 Oh crap, this is so embarrassing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Nothing to be embarrassed about. This is a very common problem, but one that's difficult to search unless you already know the answer :)